# How can I use an Azure ARM template to deploy VMs into Resource Group "A" and reference an existing key vault in Resource Group "B"?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-keyvault, azure-rm-template

I've scoured the 'net for help, but there's next to nothing on this specific issue.  My use case is that I need to create an ARM template that adds an access policy to an existing Azure key vault in one resource group, but deploy VMs into a second one.

I can deploy VMs, assign Managed Service Identities (MSIs) to them, and add those MSIs to an accessPolicy for a key vault that already exists, all the same ARM template.  The catch is, the key vault has to be in the same resource group as the VMs I'm deploying.

When I try to deploy VMs into a different resource group using the same key vault as before, I'm getting one of several errors depending on how I structure the ARM template:

1. If I reference the Key Vault as a resource in the ARM template, I get the error message "the name (keyvault-name) is already in use (Code: VaultAlreadyExists)
2. If I instead just try to use the key vault accessPolicy as a top-level resource, I get an error stating "Can not perform requested operation on nested resource. Parent resource keyvault-name not found" (Code: ParentResourceNotFound)

Really puzzling, because when I try the second method where I'm launching VMs into the same Resource Group as the VMs, it works just fine.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Cheers,

-Maashu

Comment: Can you post your ARM template please ? Otherwise it i hard to figure out what is the problem

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to perform one part of your deployment in a nested template - and then use the subscription/resourceGroup properties on that deployment to match the resourceGroup you want to deploy to (e.g. A or B).

For example (assume your KeyVault is in resourceGroup B):
1) deploy your VMs to group A (and create the MSIs)
2) in the same template add a nested deployment to group B (where KV is) after the MSIs are provisioned

See this:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.resources/deployments

Note the subscription/resourceGroup properties on the resource - this will allow you to deploy into a different resourceGroup and even a different subscription if needed.

Also: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-cross-resource-group-deployment